# How to organize tables to stare statistic of two entities?

Tags: sql, database

For now I have only two tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS company (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR (250),
    company_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES Company (id)
);
```

I need to create one or two tables to store employees and companies statistic. For employee statistic I need to remember all previous companies of this employee and of cause hire dates and resign dates. For company statistic I need to remember all resigned employees. What is the best way to organize DB structure in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have many-to-many relationship, you need an aggregate table `company_employee` that will have combined primary key, so you need:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS company (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR (250)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS company_employee (
    company_id INT NOT NULL,
    employee_id INT NOT NULL,
    hire_date DATE,
    resign_date DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES Company (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES Employee (id)
);
```

So, if you want anything from aggregate table, just use `JOIN` on key of appropriate table.